# How to use Lodash to make this mapping simpler?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I Have the following object:

```
var config = {
    apps: false,
    transfers: false,
    approvals: true
};
```

I want to know how I can use Lodash to go through each of the keys within the `config` object and find out which key has the first occurrence of value `true`. In the example above, I expect the output to be `approvals`. If the value for `transfers` was `true`, I expect the output to be `transfers`.

Basically, I want a more cleaner way to do this:

```
if (config.apps) {
    answer = 'apps';
} else if (config.transfers) {
    answer = 'transfers';
} else if (config.approvals) {
    answer = 'approvals';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need lodash for this. Loop through the object's keys, return the first result whose corresponding value is truthy. `Object.keys(config).find(prop => config[prop])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.findKey()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#findKey):

```js
var config = { apps: false, transfers: false, approvals: true };

var answer = _.findKey(config);

console.log(answer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or without lodash, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var config = { apps: false, transfers: false, approvals: true };

var answer = Object.keys(config).reduce(function(answer, key) { 
  return value = config[key] ? key : answer;
}, '');

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Why use reduce and not `Array#find`?

Comment: I'm well aware of `Array#find`, but it's not supported by internet explorer. However, if  the OP doesn't need to support IE, `Array#find` is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

No lodash required:

```
var config = {
    apps: false,
    transfers: false,
    approvals: true
};

Object.keys(config).find((key) => {
  return config[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit newer method then Object.keys is `entries` with that you can retrieve both the key and the value

```js
let config = {apps: false, transfers: false, approvals: true}
let [key, value] = Object.entries(config).find(([key, val]) => val)

console.log(key, value)
```